# Getting more detail from the Exception "ArguementException was unhandled by user code" in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

I'm new to C# so apologies if this is a really obvious question or I have the wrong terminology!

I originally compiled and ran my C# code using Microsoft Visual Studio, and when I did that I got the error message: "Arguement Exception was unhandled by user code."

I did some searching on Google and came upon this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Which showed me that I needed to put it into a try catch statement to prevent the code from stopping mid compile.

I've now done that, and the code runs without error, however I'm still stuck with the original problem of not knowing which of the parameters within my code threw the error.

```
try{
     Log.AddStatus(this.DBName, this.ID, "Error", "Error90", "Exception", "Error in Class.Method : " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.ToString() + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + Environment.NewLine + "Error Details : " + ex.Message, string.Empty);
   }
catch (ArgumentException){
       Console.WriteLine("There is an exception"); 
   }
```

Could someone show me how to pinpoint which parameter is causing the issue?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: If you use `ex.ToString()` (or in your case just `ex`, the `ToString()` will be called automatically in a string concatenation) instead of just `ex.Message`, you'll get the complete stack trace which might get you more information about the exact cause of the error. -- also, you could try changing the `catch` in your code to look like this: `catch (ArgumentException ae) { Console.WriteLine(ae); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception will already tell you what you need to know:

```
catch (ArgumentException aex)
{
   // check aex.Message here
}
```

Comment: Care to *explain* the downvote? I don't mind improving the answer, I just left my crystal ball at home.

Comment: there are serial downvoters on SO these days whose work is to downvote without reason

Comment: I imagine it will have something to do with not having something like Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); in your catch, but to be honest I think your answer is clear enough anyway.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but there is already a variable called `ex` in that scope. So maybe the variable for the `ArgumentException` should be called `ae` or something else.

Comment: yes agree with you @Corak nvoigt should have cared for that

Comment: Changed the variable naming.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Visual Studio, you should have a link in the UI that says something like "Exception details..." - clicking it will let you look at most of the exception details. (Message, Stack Trace, etc.)

And please note that in nearly all cases, `ArgumentException` should not be caught.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch your details from instance of exception as shown below :-

```
catch(ArgumentException argumentException )
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occured: " + argumentException .Message);
}
```

And you can get stacktrace detaisl, inner exception etc information from the same :-

```
Console.WriteLine(argumentException.Message);
Console.WriteLine(argumentException.StackTrace);
Console.WriteLine(argumentException.InnerException);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // you can handle all exception type in ex.Message
//also u can Exc
}
```